# How do i get a DropDownListFor to work with an IEnumerable<SelectList> with a cshtml page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My drop-down can show up but it is always empty.

I've tried using a ViewBag, a DropDownList, and List but none of these will populate the drop down for me.

Model

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AccountTypeECheck { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
ViewBag.AccountTypeECheck = new List<SelectListItem>() { 
    new SelectListItem() { 
        Value = "creditCard", 
        Text = "creditCard" 
    }
};
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "value", 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.AccountTypeECheck, 
    null, 
    new { @class ="form-control" }
)
```

Comment: What is `value`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Controller:

```
var selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Value = "creditCard", Text = "creditCard" } };
ViewBag.AccountTypeECheck = new SelectList(selectListItems, "Value", "Text");
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("AccountTypeECheck", null, new { @class ="form-control" })
```

Use the `ViewBag`'s property name (in your example `AccountTypeECheck`) as `name` parameter for `DropDownList`.

Reference: [Using the DropDownList Helper with ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for the code example.  This still has the same issue of being blank, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a model member, try this:

Model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AccountTypeECheck { get; set; }

public string AccountType {get;set;}
```

Action Method:

```
var model = new Model();
model.AccountTypeECheck = new List<SelectListItem>() { 
    new SelectListItem() { 
        Value = "creditCard", 
        Text = "creditCard" 
    }
};

return View(model);
```

View:

```
@model Model
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AccountType, Model.AccountTypeECheck)
```

Comment: I feel like that should have worked.  But, it still is an empty drop-down.  I checked the service and it's definitely returning a list items inside the AccountTypeECheck model that is of type System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem.  Is that not the correct type to use or something?  I'm assuming, though, the SelectList will iterate over the Items property inside of the model but i could be mistaken.

Comment: Place breakpoint on DropDownListFor and make sure `Model.AccountTypeECheck` contains data.

Comment: Ah, i see what happened.  I was serializing the model before i returned it and the process actually failed (albeit silently).  Thanks for the sanity check!